# Get full height of first 3 HTML elements in accordion

Tags: jquery, html

I have Bootstrap 4 accordion and need to display only first 3 elements. In result, the parent element `.panel-list` should have the full height of this three elements, also if some `.panel` is clicked and reveal `.collapse` child element with its height (this height is not added to total height of `.panel` element):

```
var count = 0;

$('.panel-list .panel:lt(3)').each(function() {
       count += $(this).height(); 
});

$('.panel-list').css({'height' : count, 'transition' : '.25s', 'overflow' : 'hidden'});

$('.loadmore_panels').on('click', function() {
    $('.panel-list')
        .attr('id', 'definitive')
        .css({'height' : 'auto', 'overflow-y' : 'visible'});
    $(this).hide();
});
```

This works fine, but it's not adding the height of `.collapse` to `.panel`, when `.panel` is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<div id="panely" class="accordion">             
    <div class="panel-list">
        <div class="panel panel-1">
            <div id="heading-1" class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
                Question 1
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-1" data-parent="#panely">
                <div class="a py-4">
                    Answer 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et sem quis felis porta egestas eget non leo.
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
                        <a href="https://example.com/services#show-projects">Case studies</a>
                        <a href="https://example.com/contact#formular">Contact</a>                              
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-2">
            <div id="heading-2" class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-2">
                Question 2
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-2" data-parent="#panely">
                <div class="a py-4">
                    answer 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et sem quis felis porta egestas eget non leo.
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
                        <a href="https://example.com/services#show-projects">Case studies</a>
                        <a href="https://example.com/contact#formular">Contact</a>                              
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-3">
            <div id="heading-3" class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-3">
                Question 3
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-3" data-parent="#panely">
                <div class="a py-4">
                    Answer 3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et sem quis felis porta egestas eget non leo.
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
                        <a href="https://example.com/services#show-projects">Case studies</a>
                        <a href="https://example.com/contact#formular">Contact</a>                              
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-4">
            <div id="heading-4" class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-4" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-4">
                Question 4
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-4" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-4" data-parent="#panely">
                <div class="a py-4">
                    answer 4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et sem quis felis porta egestas eget non leo.
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
                        <a href="https://example.com/services#show-projects">Case studies</a>
                        <a href="https://example.com/contact#formular">Contact</a>                              
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-5">
            <div id="heading-5" class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-5" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-5">
                Question 5
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-5" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-5" data-parent="#panely">
                <div class="a py-4">
                    answer 5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et sem quis felis porta egestas eget non leo.
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
                        <a href="https://example.com/services#show-projects">Case studies</a>
                        <a href="https://example.com/contact#formular">Contact</a>                              
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>

<div class="loadmore_panels btn btn-primary">Show more</div>
```

**CODEPEN** https://codepen.io/trueweb/pen/MWYPNyd?editors=1010

Comment: https://codepen.io/bZez/pen/povxMQo?editors=0010 like that ?

Comment: Yes, perfect! It works :) Make this please as answer, so I can accept and rate it.

Comment: It's Done Juraj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you dont need use JavaScript to get et set heights from panel.
Prefer use the power of bootstrap classes and a css selector with javascript.

Use CSS `nth-child(n+4)` selector to select all panel from 4th.

Add `'d-none'` bootsrap's class (to hide them)

```
$('div.panel:nth-child(n+4)').addClass('d-none');
```

Simply toggle display c

```
$('.loadmore_panels').click(function(){
$('.panel + .d-none').toggleClass('d-done d-block')
})
```

Here's my working example:
https://codepen.io/bZez/pen/povxMQo

```js
$('div.panel:nth-child(n+4)').addClass('d-none');
$('.loadmore_panels').click(function(){
$('.panel + .d-none').toggleClass('d-done d-block')
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="panely" class="accordion">
    <div class="panel-list">
        <div class="panel panel-1">
            <div id="heading-1" class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
                    Question 1
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-1" data-parent="#panely">
                <div class="a py-4">
                    Answer 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et sem quis felis porta egestas eget non leo.
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
                        <a href="https://example.com/services#show-projects">Case studies</a>
                        <a href="https://example.com/contact#formular">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-2">
            <div id="heading-2" class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-2">
                    Question 2
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-2" data-parent="#panely">
                <div class="a py-4">
                    answer 2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et sem quis felis porta egestas eget non leo.
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
                        <a href="https://example.com/services#show-projects">Case studies</a>
                        <a href="https://example.com/contact#formular">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-3">
            <div id="heading-3" class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-3">
                    Question 3
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-3" data-parent="#panely">
                <div class="a py-4">
                    Answer 3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et sem quis felis porta egestas eget non leo.
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
                        <a href="https://example.com/services#show-projects">Case studies</a>
                        <a href="https://example.com/contact#formular">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-4">
            <div id="heading-4" class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-4" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-4">
                    Question 4
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-4" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-4" data-parent="#panely">
                <div class="a py-4">
                    answer 4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et sem quis felis porta egestas eget non leo.
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
                        <a href="https://example.com/services#show-projects">Case studies</a>
                        <a href="https://example.com/contact#formular">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-5">
            <div id="heading-5" class="panel-heading">
                <button class="btn w-100 text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-5" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-5">
                    Question 5
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse-5" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-5" data-parent="#panely">
                <div class="a py-4">
                    answer 5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et sem quis felis porta egestas eget non leo.
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
                        <a href="https://example.com/services#show-projects">Case studies</a>
                        <a href="https://example.com/contact#formular">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="loadmore_panels btn btn-primary">Show more</div>
```